# biblatex author (year) citations

Tags: biblatex

What is the biblatex equivalent of `\citeasnoun{}` from the harvard bibliography style?  For example, we cite like Marx (1867).  (The open-paren does not go before Marx.)

Comment: Use `\textcite`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\textcite`. And you need an author-year style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{shore}, \cite{shore}, \parencite{shore}

\end{document}
```